# "ScrollView" doesn't scroll the elements inside it

Tags: javascript, react-native

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm just learning, so please don't judge me harshly. I wanted to scroll to the product page. But, after adding it, it doesn't work... Actually, that's the problem. I've tried many different ways, but something has not worked yet.

Comment: Hello! Could you paste the code instead of adding images??

Comment: Always add code not srenshot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try importing the ScrollView from React-Native-Gesture-Handler instead of importing it from React-native. also npm install React-Native-Gesture-Handler if you don't have it.